# Making a music player in C++/GTK

Tags: c++, gtk

I would like to create a music player, but I'm working with robots.

My robot should play a series of action (speech, move, etc) and I need to be able to stop it at anytime (for security).

I'm working with C++ and GTK.

I have a <kbd>PLAY</kbd> button linked to the function `play_playlist`:

```
void play_playlist ()
{
    std::deque<history_record>::iterator it = list_to_play_.begin();
    while (!g_stop_ && it != list_to_play_.end())
    {
        play_action(it); // take time to execute (simulate using sleep 3sec)
        it++;
    }
}
```

And a <kbd>STOP</kbd> button linked to the function `set_stop_to_false`:

```
void set_stop_to_true()
{
    g_stop_ = true;
}
```

When I click <kbd>PLAY</kbd> the GUI freezes and I'm not able to click on <kbd>STOP</kbd>.

**How can I have my playlist running and be able to click on the GUI?** (i.e. GUI should be responsive)

My best hope is a thread, but I'm not sure how to use it appropriately.

Comment: Take a look at [Gstreamer](http://http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). That framework works around an event loop just the same as **Gtk+** making it easily work together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *When I click <kbd>PLAY</kbd> the GUI freezes and I'm not able to click on <kbd>STOP</kbd>.*

You need to build a *multi-threaded application*. Your interface freezes because your application is busy doing something else, so not only that events raised from GUI are not being processed but they are not even raised.

Your application should start a worker thread that will do its job in the background, the main thread can then communicate with this worker thread for example via *shared memory*.

Answer (score 0):

Once you enter a callback like `play_playlist`, the GTK main loop can't process events until you exit that function, which freezes the user interface. As `play_action` takes seconds to run, you only have 2 choices:

1. split play_playlist execution in several smaller steps, and use a
   state machine to execute each step one after the other using a
   callback triggered by `g_idle_add`. Here's an example of this
   technique for [lazy loading](http://web.archive.org/web/20080321054327/http://log.emmanuelebassi.net/documentation/lazy-loading/).
2. the other solution is to run your blocking `play_action` in a thread. Give a look at GThread. You start your thread when you press PLAY and stop it when you press STOP. However, you can't manipulate the user interface from a thread, GTK is not thread safe. Every GTK action should be processed from the main thread.